# Azure Pipeline : How to release Project binary file into Azure machine

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, binaryfiles

**Azure DevOps Pipeline : How to release Project binary file into Azure.**

How can I deploy project binary files into server using Azure Pipeline, don't want to release project full source code?

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=vsts).

1. create a deployment group
2. create a build, configure it
3. create a release, configure it (get artifacts from build, deploy to deployment group)

These are the steps you need to perform. link has more information on this matter

Comment: Thank you for response,  How can i generate binary files of source code and then deploy to Azure?

Comment: this is an overly general question. you have build steps for each type of project: java\nodejs\c# etc. you run those with proper inputs and they give you the result

Comment: If we have already generated file `my-perfect-software-v2.5.1-x86_64.tar.gz`, there should be some general way to release a `file`. Azure must not care about if I'm building it with C++/Go/Java

Comment: yeah, just use `upload an artifact` task